# $.click() and $.trigger() does not activate the onchange function of a Checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to programmatically check a checkbox and trigger the checkbox's onchange function

I have tried `("#myCheckbox").click()` but it only checks it and does not call its onchange function

How can I get the onchange function to execute as well?

**edit:**

When the document is ready i need the checkbox checked and its on change function called programatically.

Comment: $('#myId').trigger('change');

Comment: How is the `onchange` function defined? As an HTML attribute?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your change listener needs to be set **before** you trigger the click on the checkbox. The following code works with no issues:

```
$("#myCheckbox").on('change', function(){
   console.log('Change'); 
}).click();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x7ZWB/)

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
$('#myCheckbox').prop({ checked: true });
theOnchangeFunction();
```

---

```
$('#myCheckbox').on('change', theOnchangeFunction);
```

---

```
function theOnchangeFunction(){

}
```

Comment: I was typing something like this. This is the way to go!

Comment: +1 for the use of an object in the `prop` call.  I didn't know about that!

Comment: @Archer I tend to use it in quite a lot of jQuery methods. `.css()` is another common use case, since you usually want to pass more than one property.

Comment: I knew about using it in `css`, but not in this way.  Thanks for the eye-opener :)

Answer (score 1):

you can try like below

```
 $("#scheck").attr('checked', 'checked').change();
```

it will check the check box as well trigger onchange event for checkbox

ex:

Script :

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#scheck").attr('checked', 'checked').change();
    });      

    function checkitout() {
        alert("onchange event fired");
    }
```

HTML :

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="tdcheck" id="scheck" onchange="checkitout();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't understand, it works : http://jsfiddle.net/FW5Lp/

```
<input type="checkbox" id="myc">
    <button id='clic'>click</button>

$('#myc').on('change', function(){alert('ca change');});

$('#clic').on('click', function(){$('#myc').trigger('click') });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try both `events` by using [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) like,

```
("#myCheckbox").on('click change',function(e){
    alert(e.type);
})
```